# Using UIPageViewControllers scroll over entire view, including UIButtons

Tags: swift, scroll, uibutton, swipe, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIView with a PageViewController and 4 UIButtons as subviews. The PageViewController and the button subviews are independent from each other. (PageViewController scrolls across 4 pages while the UIButtons remain constant)

The problem I'm facing is that the buttons take quite a bit of space and I'd like to use this scroll gesture anywhere on the UIView including the areas with buttons.

If the user taps on the button, its respective action would occur but I'd like if I can START a scroll/swipe gesture on a button and have the PageViewControllers scroll feature work.

I've tried/searched several ways including using UIScrollView instead of a PageViewController. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Have you tried adding a gesture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add your own gesture recogniser and watch for gestures which velocity is greater in the x direction and going from left to right.

```
    override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

        if (gestureRecognizer.isMemberOfClass(UIPanGestureRecognizer)){
            let point:CGPoint = (gestureRecognizer as UIPanGestureRecognizer).velocityInView(self)
            if (abs(point.x) > abs(point.y)){
                return true
            }
        }
}
```

Handle the gesture over here:

```
func handlePanGestureRecognizer(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    let translation:CGPoint = gesture.translationInView(self)
    if(translation.x > 0){
       //its going from left to right...
       //...transition to the previous page
    }else{
       //...transition to the next page
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much man. I've yet to try it (working on some other kinks first) but I think it should work. :)